# Can't see source java class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse neon.

I have a JAR filed stored in my `lib` directory. I have a class that uses that jar file but when I do a `ctrl + click` on one of the classes in that jar then I get a source not found. I am trying to look at the code of that class.

---

This isn't a duplicate question because the others questions similar to this relates to debugging.

Comment: Hm.... you're trying to access the class from the jar file?

Comment: Well the library jar file usually doesn't contain the source code...

Comment: @Aaron I am trying to access the jar class, from a class I am writing, that uses it.

Comment: @Zircon but doesn't eclipse have a build in plugin where it decompiles that `.class` file for you ?

Comment: just drag the .class file where the other files are and it should open up

Comment: @robben That's different from seeing the source, especially if there's no debug info in the file. But view source is different than decompiling.

Comment: IntelliJ has that feature, dunno about Eclipse, but either way relying on decompilers is bad news. If it's open source, a build tool like Maven or Gradle will pull source in for you and build a new jar.

Comment: @nonconvergent Yep, I used intelliJ before and never had this issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton So there is no way I can see the source even though I don't know where the source is?

Comment: @robben If *you* don't know where it is how could Eclipse? You can try decompiling it, which may or may not be useful. I don't know how to do that on current Eclipse.

Comment: @DaveNewton So are you saying i have to find the source of all my `.class` files and attach them to see the source? There has to be a better way. I know IntelliJ does it. I never had this issue with IntelliJ.

Comment: Again: decompiling is an option; you're at the mercy of what's in the .class file. IntelliJ works the same way: you can't show data that isn't there. IntelliJ explicitly states when it's showing decompiled code and gives you the option of downloading a source jar if available or attaching your own sources. You can configure IntelliJ to automatically download sources, but that's still attaching source. Decompiling in Eclipse works the same way (or at least used to, but I don't know what decompiler it uses; IntelliJ uses Fernflower, at least back in v14).